kivy: decorate setter-function (EventDispatcher)
The following kv-code places an image inside a button and scales it, depending on the button's size:
   Button:                                                                          
    text:'Katze'                                                                 
    background_color: ('#00ffff')                                                
    font_size: 32                                                                
    on_press:root.playSound(self)                                                
    Image:                                                                       
        source: './katze.png'                                                    
        center_x: self.parent.center_x                                           
        center_y: self.parent.center_y                                           
        size: root.width*0.25, root.height*0.25

Is there a way to reproduce this in python?
I have an approximate solution with the help of this post
kivy widgets : multiple buttons, centering, get window/screen dimensions, now my question is:
Can I decorate the setter functions (below) of the image objects so that the length and width parameters can be changed? For example, to a quarter of their values? I am new to Python and have spent some time trying to understand the decorator principle, but have not yet been able to find a solution.
def build(self):
    self.layout = GridLayout(cols=3, spacing=10)
    for animal in self.zoo:
        knopf = ButtonID(
            id = animal, #member ButtonID(Button)
            background_color=get_color_from_hex(self.zoo[animal][0]),
            on_press =  self.playSound,                             
        )
        self.layout.add_widget(knopf)
        
        bild=Image()
        knopf.add_widget(bild)
        bild.source=self.animal[tier][2]
                                                               
        knopf.bind(center=bild.setter('center'))
        #knopf.bind(width=bild.setter('width'))                                                     
        #knopf.bind(height=bild.setter('height'))                                                   
        knopf.bind(size=bild.setter('size'))

    return self.layout

Greetings,
michael

The Builder does not translate the kv language into Python,  it creates its own rules by parsing the kv code, and uses those rules to create widgets.

Oh well, then I had bought it wrong. Thanks for the hint.

After studying the decorator concept, I found a solution. Here is the source code for automatically generated buttons with embedded images, which are always nicely scaled via bindings and a decorator.
This program shows buttons with animal icons. When you press the buttons, a sound file with the corresponding animal voice is played. Served as motivation in a programming course on kivy. Was a lot of fun.
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.lang import Builder

import sys

class ButtonID(Button):
    def __init__(self, id, **kwargs):
        super(Button, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.id=id

    def update(self, *kargs):
        print("groesse: ", self.size)
        print("position: ", self.pos)
        #self.canvas.clear() 
        with self.canvas:
            pass
        
class ZooApp(App):

    zoo = {"Vogel":["00FFFF", "./birds_cardinal.mp3","./vogel.png"],
           "Katze":["DDA0DD", "./cat_meow_04.mp3","./katze.png"],
           "Kuh":["E2DDD5", "./cows_two_cows_mooing.mp3","./kuh.png"],
           "Esel":["FFFF00", "./donkey_braying.mp3","./esel.png"],
           "Schwein":["FFD700", "./pig_grunt.mp3","./schwein.png"],
           "Schaf":["FF8C00", "./sheep_bleat_001.mp3","./schaf.png"],
           "Lanz":["E2DDD5","./lanz_bulldog_trim.mp3","./lanzFrei.png"]}

    def playSound(self, button):
        SoundLoader.load(filename=self.zoo[button.id][1]).play()
        
    def build(self):
        self.title = "Kleintier-Zoo"
        self.layout = GridLayout(cols =3, spacing = 10) 
        for tier in self.zoo:
            knopf = ButtonID(
                id = tier,
                background_color = get_color_from_hex(self.zoo[tier][0]),
                on_press =  self.playSound, # play-sound = callback-fkt
            )

            self.layout.add_widget(knopf)

            bild=Image()

            knopf.add_widget(bild)
            bild.source=self.zoo[tier][2]
                
            def dekorateur(func):
                def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                    erstes=args[0] #scheint button-id zu sein
                    zweites=args[1]
                    zweites=zweites/2
                    args=(erstes,zweites)
                    print("args: ", erstes, zweites)
                    print("kwargs: ", kwargs)
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                return wrapper

            knopf.bind(center=bild.setter('center'))
            
            setterfunktion = bild.setter('width')
            setterfunktion=dekorateur(setterfunktion)
            knopf.bind(width=setterfunktion)

            setterfunktion = bild.setter('height')
            setterfunktion=dekorateur(setterfunktion)
            knopf.bind(height=setterfunktion)

            
        return self.layout
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ZooApp().run()

